# Excel Macro to insert or delete rows based on the number of rows between two cells with data

Tags: vba, excel

I am stating with something like One name has three blank lines Next has two, then four, then three, and so on

and I am looking for an end result where for each name there are two blank rows

This is what I currently have and it is not working it just adds a line under the first name

```
Dim c As Range
Dim counting As Boolean
Dim zeroCount As Long

For Each c In activeSheet.[A2:A30].Cells
    If Len(c) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    Else
        If Not c.Value2 = "" Then
            counting = True
            Do While Not zeroCount = 3
                If zeroCount < 2 Then
                    c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    zeroCount = zeroCount + 1
                End If
                If zeroCount > 3 Then
                    c.Offset(1, 0).Delete Shift:=x1Up
                    zeroCount = zeroCount - 1
                End If
                End
            Loop
            zeroCount = 0
        Else
            If counting Then
                zeroCount = zeroCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to delete all blank rows, then do a simple loop to add 2 in?  You could run a loop to delete a row if it's blank, or make it autofilter and sort alphabetically, so all the blank rows move to the end.

Comment: Ok there was something I forgot to mention and I just thought about it when I read your comment.
After one row with a name and then the blank rows there is also a rows and before the next name there is a blue fill from a:g to separate each persons task would that still be easily done in the way you just described?

Comment: It sounds like you want to clear all blank rows first, then run a loop that will insert two blank rows and a blue row in between each row?  First remove the blank rows, either by autofiltering (faster) or using a loop (easier to code), Something like if cells(x,1) = "" then rows(x).delete .  Then do another loop- rows(x).insert , rows(x).insert, rows(x).insert, range("A" & x+3 & ":G" & x+3).interior.color= rgb(0,0,255) , x = x + 4 .  It looks like you've made progress, in my view it'd be best to start by clearing all blank lines.  If I can provide any other help I will-

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Acantud this is working much as I wanted it to

> It sounds like you want to clear all blank rows first, then run a loop that will insert two blank rows and a blue row in between each row? First remove the blank rows, either by autofiltering (faster) or using a loop (easier to code), Something like if cells(x,1) = "" then rows(x).delete . Then do another loop- rows(x).insert , rows(x).insert, rows(x).insert, range("A" & x+3 & ":G" & x+3).interior.color= rgb(0,0,255) , x = x + 4 . It looks like you've made progress, in my view it'd be best to start by clearing all blank lines. If I can provide any other help I will- –  Acantud 19 hours ago

This is what I ended up having at the end

```
Dim cnt As Integer

Range("A2:A26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
With activeSheet
    cnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


For i = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row To 3 Step -1
    'Gives rows to the last person
    If i = cnt Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
    End If
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
    Range("A" & i, "G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(197, 217, 241)
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromAbove
Next i
```

This works great thanks